# how to prevent users from overwriting each other's data

Tags: pouchdb

For pouchdb, it supports remote sync with a server-side DB.

http://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html

However, for a multi-user app, it seems the client can simply change the database name to anything, and may even overwrite other users' data.

How to prevent this? Create a separate DB for each user?

Answer (score 1):

"DB per user" is a pretty standard authentication model in CouchDB/PouchDB. (Don't worry - databases are cheap in CouchDB.) There are some examples of different recipes [in the pouchdb-authentication README](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication#couchdb-authentication-recipes) as well as [a more complex example](https://speakerdeck.com/bigbluehat/federation-for-alice-bob-and-charlie) where multiple users partially share data amongst themselves.